# Updating Data Extension field

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I want to update the field name of an existing DE but the below request is failing with 'Bad Request' message. What could be wrong?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>{{User}}</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">{{Pwd}}</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:body>
  <updaterequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
     <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
        <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts> // to enable child accounts
        <CustomerKey>ManeeshAPI</CustomerKey> 
         <fields>
           <field>
              <ObjectID>f91787bb-5450-458c-a68a-f8c5bb977cbc</ObjectID>
              <Name>First Name</Name>
              <MaxLength>90</MaxLength>
           </field>
        </fields>
   </updaterequest>
</soapenv:body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: the `// to enable child accounts` is probably an issue.

Comment: I removed that and tried but still the same error. 
This DE is in a Child BU. Does that change anything in the call?

Comment: This one has me stumped. I can add additional fields to a DE, but cannot seem to update them (I've tried many different permutations). It returns an OK message and the DE modified date changes, but the fields do not update. Odd. Let me know if you solve this mystery!

Comment: Tried everything but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Below is the call that works for DE field update -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5501096" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>xxxx</wsse:Username> 
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password> 
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options /> 
        <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Client>
           <ID>6226040</ID>
        </Client>
        <CustomerKey>3ECC8D95-5850-4A6C-8544-838E2FC05AEC</CustomerKey>
        <Fields>
           <Field>
              <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ObjectID>0aeba7d0-e233-49ad-ab90-b8c2168d17b7</ObjectID>
              <MaxLength>70</MaxLength>
           </Field>
            </Fields>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Bad request 400` usually indicates your XML request is not in valid format
   For DE field update request XML example, see [**Updating Column Properties for an Existing Data Extension**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_column_properties_for_an_existing_data_extension.htm)

   try objects `xsi:type="DataExtension"` instead of `ObjectType`
    If you sending XML to endpoint, make sure it is POST not GET, you also need to have these two in headers:

   `Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8`

   `SOAPAction:"Update"`
2. `QueryAllAccounts` is for `RetrieveRequest` not for [**UpdateRequest**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateresult.htm), try removing it and adding child BU ClientID attribute. Do you see same problem if you try updating a test DE in parent BU?

   `<Client><ID>12345</ID></Client>`

Comment: Tried everything but nothing worked